# How do you convert a slice into an array?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I am trying to write an application that reads RPM files.  The start of each block has a Magic char of `[4]byte`.

Here is my struct

```
type Lead struct {
  Magic        [4]byte
  Major, Minor byte
  Type         uint16
  Arch         uint16
  Name         string
  OS           uint16
  SigType      uint16
}
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
lead := Lead{}
lead.Magic = buffer[0:4]
```

I am searching online and not sure how to go from a slice to an array (without copying).  I can always make the Magic `[]byte` (or even `uint64`), but I was more curious on how would I go from type `[]byte` to `[4]byte` if needed to?

Comment: @fuz 7+ years later, with the new Go 1.17 (Q3 2021), you will have a conversion from a slice to an array pointer indeed: `(*[4]byte)(buffer)`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67199587/6309)

Comment: Go 1.18 (Q4 2021): `*(*[N]T)(d) = [N]T(s)`. See my [edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67199587/6309)

Comment: @ekaqu "slice to an array (without copying)" what do you mean? When the accepted answer does a copy?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The built in method *copy* will only copy a slice to a slice NOT a slice to an array.

You must trick *copy* into thinking the array is a slice

```
copy(varLead.Magic[:], someSlice[0:4])
```

Or use a for loop to do the copy:

```
for index, b := range someSlice {

    varLead.Magic[index] = b

}
```

Or do as zupa has done using literals. I have added onto their working example.

[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ZGqRAarFEH)

Comment: doing [0:3] will only copy the first 3 elements, not all four. as otherwise suggested, do [0:4]

Comment: You could also use `copy(varLead.Magic[:], someSlice[:])`. This would copy all the content that fits into the array.

Comment: Well just `copy(varLead.Magic[:], someSlice)` is enough since it will only copy the contents that fit to the array.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
copy(lead.Magic[:], buf[0:4])
```

Answer (score 11):

You have allocated four bytes inside that struct and want to assign a value to that four byte section.  There is no conceptual way to do that without copying.

Look at the `copy` built-in for how to do that.

Answer (score 6):

[Tapir Liui](https://twitter.com/TapirLiu/) ([auteur de Go101](https://github.com/go101/go101)) [twitte](https://twitter.com/go100and1/status/1430350025985454085):

> Go <del>1.18</del> <del>1.19</del> 1.20 will support conversions from slice to array: [`golang/go` issues 46505](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46505).

So, since Go 1.18,the slice copy2 implementation could be written as:

```
*(*[N]T)(d) = [N]T(s)
```

or, even simpler if the conversion is allowed to present as L-values:

```
[N]T(d) = [N]T(s)
```

---

Without copy, you can convert, with the next Go 1.17 (Q3 2021) a slice to an array *pointer*.

This is called "un-slicing", giving you back a pointer to the [underlying array of a slice](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro#TOC_4.), again, without any copy/allocation needed:

[image: https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro/slice-1.png]

See [`golang/go` issue 395: `spec: convert slice x into array pointer`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/395), now implemented with [CL 216424/](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/216424/), and [commit 1c26843](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/1c268431f49ee2fc843eac52a0854aea3d02a6e0)

> Converting a slice to an array pointer yields a pointer to the underlying array of the slice.
> If the length of the slice is less than the length of the array,
> a run-time panic occurs.

```golang
s := make([]byte, 2, 4)
s0 := (*[0]byte)(s)      // s0 != nil
s2 := (*[2]byte)(s)      // &amp;s2[0] == &amp;s[0]
s4 := (*[4]byte)(s)      // panics: len([4]byte) > len(s)

var t []string
t0 := (*[0]string)(t)    // t0 == nil
t1 := (*[1]string)(t)    // panics: len([1]string) > len(s)
```

So in your case, provided `Magic` type is `*[4]byte`:

```
lead.Magic = (*[4]byte)(buffer)
```

Note: type aliasing will work too:

```golang
type A [4]int
var s = (*A)([]int{1, 2, 3, 4})
```

---

Why convert to an array pointer? As explained in [issue 395](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/395):

> One motivation for doing this is that using an array pointer allows the compiler to range check constant  indices **at compile time**.
>
> A function like this:
>
> ```golang
> func foo(a []int) int
> {
>    return a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3];
> }
> ```
>
> could be turned into:
>
> ```golang
> func foo(a []int) int
> {
>    b := (*[4]int)(a)
>    return b[0] + b[1] + b[2] + b[3];
> }
> ```
>
> allowing the compiler to check all the bounds once only and give compile-time errors about out of range  indices.

[Also](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/395#issuecomment-66049551):

> One well-used example is making classes as small as possible for tree nodes or linked list nodes so you can cram as many of them into L1 cache lines as possible.
> This is done by each node having a single pointer to a left sub-node, and the right sub-node being accessed by the pointer to the left sub-node + 1.
> This saves the 8-bytes for the right-node pointer.
>
> To do this you have to pre-allocate all the nodes in a vector or array so they're laid out in memory sequentially, but it's worth it when you need it for performance.
> (This also has the added benefit of the prefetchers being able to help things along performance-wise - at least in the linked list case)
>
> You can *almost* do this in Go with:
>
> ```golang
>   type node struct {
>      value int
>      children *[2]node
>   }
> ```
>
> except that there's no way of getting a `*[2]node` from the underlying slice.

---

Go 1.20 (Q1 2023): this is addressed with [CL 430415](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/430415/), [428938 (type)](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/428938/), [430475 (reflect)](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/430475/) and [429315 (spec)](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/429315/).

Comment: In the end the conversion from slice to array didn't make it into 1.18. Probably 1.19.

Comment: @DuncanHarris Thank you for the update. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

#### Go 1.20

You can convert from a slice to an array directly with the usual conversion syntax `T(x)`. The array's length can't be greater than the slice's length:

```
func main() {
    slice := []int64{10, 20, 30, 40}
    array := [4]int64(slice)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", array) // [4]int64
}
```

#### Go 1.17

Starting from Go 1.17 you can [directly convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_from_slice_to_array_pointer) a slice to an array *pointer*. With Go's type conversion syntax `T(x)` you can do this:

```
slice := make([]byte, 4)
arrptr := (*[4]byte)(slice)
```

Keep in mind that the length of the array must not be greater than the length of the slice, otherwise the conversion will panic.

```
bad := (*[5]byte)(slice) // panics: slice len < array len
```

This conversion has the advantage of **not making any copy**, because it simply yields a pointer to the underlying array.

Of course you can dereference the array pointer to obtain a non-pointer array variable, so the following also works:

```
slice := make([]byte, 4)
var arr [4]byte = *(*[4]byte)(slice)
```

However dereferencing and assigning **will subtly make a copy**, since the `arr` variable is now [initialized](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) to the value that results from the conversion expression. To be clear (using ints for simplicity):

```
v := []int{10,20}
a := (*[2]int)(v)

a[0] = 500
fmt.Println(v) // [500 20] (changed, both point to the same backing array)

w := []int{10,20}
b := *(*[2]int)(w)

b[0] = 500
fmt.Println(w) // [10 20] (unchanged, b holds a copy)
```

---

One might wonder why the conversion checks the slice length *and not the capacity* (I did). Consider the following program:

```
func main() {
    a := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6}
    fmt.Println(cap(a)) // 6

    b := a[:3]
    fmt.Println(cap(a)) // still 6

    c := (*[3]int)(b)

    ptr := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&c[0]))
    ptr += 3 * unsafe.Sizeof(int(0))

    i := (*int)(unsafe.Pointer(ptr))
    fmt.Println(*i) // 4
}
```

The program shows that the conversion might happen after reslicing. The original backing array with six elements is still there, so one might wonder why a runtime panic occurs with `(*[6]int)(b)` where `cap(b) == 6`.

This has actually been [brought up](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/395#issuecomment-799707650). It's worth to remember that, unlike slices, an array has *fixed size*, therefore it needs no notion of capacity, only length:

```
a := [4]int{1,2,3,4}
fmt.Println(len(a) == cap(a)) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do the whole thing with one read, instead of reading individually into each field. If the fields are fixed-length, then you can do:

```
lead := Lead{}

// make a reader to dispense bytes so you don't have to keep track of where you are in buffer
reader := bytes.NewReader(buffer)

// read into each field in Lead, so Magic becomes buffer[0:4],
// Major becomes buffer[5], Minor is buffer[6], and so on...
binary.Read(reader, binary.LittleEndian, &lead)
```

Answer (score -3):

Don't. Slice itself is suffice for all purpose. Array in go lang should be regarded as the underlying structure of slice. In every single case, use only slice. You don't have to array yourself. You just do everything by slice syntax. Array is only for computer. In most cases, slice is better, clear in code. Even in other cases, slice still is sufficient to reflex your idea.

Comment: In *general* slices may be preferred over arrays but there are places where arrays are appropriate and superior. Saying "In every single case, use only slice" is wrong.

Comment: An example of where arrays are necessary: as a member of a struct that must be comparable (e.g. for using it as a map key).

Comment: I use arrays for semantic, to say that the code below will not append into this structure. Also for performance, why not.