# How can I convert from []byte to [16]byte?

Tags: go

I have this code:

```
func my_function(hash string) [16]byte {
    b, _ := hex.DecodeString(hash)
    return b   // Compile error: fails since [16]byte != []byte
}
```

`b` will be of type `[]byte`. I know that `hash` is of length 32. How can I make my code above work? Ie. can I somehow cast from a general-length byte array to a fixed-length byte array? I am not interested in allocating 16 new bytes and copying the data over.

Comment: As in copying a slice to an array? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21399657/6309

Comment: No. I prefer to not copy. Added that to question.

Comment: Not convertible without `unsafe`. The slice header itself is 24 bytes on amd64 and is copied to the stack when `hex.DecodeString` returns, and hashing itself is going to be far, far more expensive than copying a 16-byte result; I'd pick your battles and not worry too much about this one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no direct method to convert a slice to an array. You can however do a copy.

```
var ret [16]byte
copy(ret[:], b)
```

The standard library uses []byte and if you insist on using something else you will just have a lot more typing to do. I wrote a program using arrays for my md5 values and regretted it.

Comment: Notice that you can usually make sure that data you receive ends up in an array variable by slicing the array variable (e.g. `foo[:]`). This is useful when you want to actually use arrays for performance reasons but you still want to `Read()` and `Write()` into them.