# How can I cast []byte to [8]uint8

Tags: go

I need to populate a struct that has a member of type `[8]uint8`. This needs be populated with a byte array of type `[]byte` initialized to length 8. The simplistic approach does not work:

```
Data:   [8]uint8(RequestFrame(0x180, r)),
```

gives

```
cannot convert .. (type []byte) to type [8]uint8
```

Since both arrays are structurally identical it would be nice if this could be done with casting/assignment rather than copying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Background

The problem with your "simplistic approach" is that a slice
(of any type) is a `struct`-typed value consisting of a pointer
and two integers; the pointer contains the address of the
underlying (backing) data array, and the integers contain
what `len()` and `cap()` builtins return for that slice.

In other words, a slice is sort of *a view into* an array.

Then, in Go, there is no concept of a type cast; there are only
type conversions, and these conversions may only happen between
types with the same *underlying representation¹.*

Since a slice and an array may not have the same underlying
representation (array is literally a contiguous block of memory
of the size just enough to contain all the array's elements),
your alleged type conversion may not be legal.

### Possible solutions

There are two possible solutions.

The simplest is to just copy the data from the slice's
backing array into a newly-allocated array:

```
var (
    src = []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
    dst [8]uint8
)
copy(dst[:], src[:8])
```

Note that there exists an inherent disparity between slice an
array types: an array type encodes both the type of its elements
and its length (that is, the length is a part of the type),
while a slice type only encodes the type of its elements
(and may be of any length at runtime).

This means that you might need to have a check before such
copying that makes sure the source slice has exactly 8
elements, that is, `len(src) == len(dst)`.

This invariant may be enforced by some other code, but I think
I'd warn you up front about this: if `src` has less than 8
elements, the `src[:8]` expression will panic at runtime,
and if it contains more, then there's the question of whether
copying just the first 8 of them is exactly what's needed.

The second approach (admittedly messier) is to just re-use
the underlying array of the slice:

```
import "unsafe"

var (
    src    = []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
    dstPtr *[8]uint8
)

if len(src) != len(*dstPtr) {
    panic("boom")
}
dstPtr = (*[8]uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(&src[0]))
```

Here, we've just taken the address of the first element
contained in the slice's underlying array and peformed
a "dirty" two-phase type-conversion to make the obtained
pointer to be of type `*[8]uint8`—that is, "an address of
an array of 8 `uint8`s".

Note two caveats:

- The resulting pointer now points to
  the same memory block the original slice does.
  It means it's now possible to mutate that memory both through the
  slice and the pointer we obtained.
- As soon as you'll decide to assign the array's data
  to a variable of type `[8]uint8` (and passing it as an argument
  to a function's parameter of that type), you will dereference
  that pointer (like with `*dstPtr`), and at that moment
  *the array's data will be **copied.***

  I'm specifically mentioning this as often people resort
  to hacks like this one to pull the backing array out of
  a slice precisely in an attempt to not copy the memory.

#### TL;DR

Copy the data (after supposedly verifying the
`len(src) == len(dst)` invariant holds).

Copying 8 bytes is fast (on a typical 64-bit CPU this will be
a single `MOV` instruction, or two at most), and the code will
be straightforward.

Only resort to hacks from the second solution when you really
need to optimize on some critical hot path.
In that case, comment the solution extensively and watch for
not accidentally dereferencing your pointer.

---

¹ There are notable exceptions to this rule:

- A `[]byte` is type-convertible to `string`, and vice-versa.
- A `string` is type-convertible to `[]rune`, and vice-versa.
- An `int` is type-convertible to `string` (but since Go 1.15 `go vet` [gives a warning about it](https://golang.org/doc/go1.15#vet), and this feature may probably be prohibited in the future).

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the contents of your `byte` slice into your `uint8` array very simply by using `copy`, like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    slice := []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

    array := [8]uint8{}

    copy(array[:], slice)

    fmt.Println(array)
}
```

Outputs

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

[Try it out on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tjw_SDz7Pt4).

But may I ask why you are using an array? It's usually better to just use slices, unless you have a really good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Go 1.17 you are able to use type conversion directly, from a [slice to an array pointer](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_from_slice_to_array_pointer):

```
    a := make([]byte, 8)
    b := (*[8]uint8)(a) // b is pointer to [8]uint8
```

The you can just dereference to obtain a non-pointer `[8]uint8` type.

```
    a := make([]byte, 8)
    b := *(*[8]uint8)(a) // b is [8]uint8
```

Notes:

- unlike `copy`, the conversion approach **does not incur in extra allocations** (not yours, nor any possibly done by `copy`), because it simply yields a pointer to the existing backing array. Though dereferencing the array pointer [will make a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443348/does-dereferencing-a-struct-return-a-new-copy-of-struct).
- the conversion panics if the length of the array is greater than the slice's

```
a := make([]byte, 5)
b := (*[10]byte)(a) // panics
```

- the pointer points to the slice's underlying array, therefore the same values will be visible by indexing either:

```
    a := []byte{0xa1, 0xa2}
    b := (*[2]uint8)(a)

    fmt.Printf("%x\n", a[0]) // a1
    b[0] = 0xff
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", a[0]) // ff
```

- you can convert from `byte` to `uint8`, including type literals derived from them, because byte is an **alias** (identical to) of uint8.

Related: [How do you convert a slice into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073769)